# How use loops by datetime each on weekly in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime, loops, data-binding, foreach

i try loop while with datetime each on weekly in VB.NET 2008.

**This Code**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()....
        'Select DateTime 
        Dim strDate As Date = dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

        'one week (+7)
        Dim strDateWeek As String = DateAdd("d", +7, dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))

        'DateCurrent
        Dim strDateNow As String = DateAdd("d", 0, Now.ToLongDateString())

        'While strDate < strDateNow
            'ListBox1.Items.Add(strDateWeek)
        'End While
        ListBox1.Items.Add(strDateWeek)
End Sub
```

**Example**

```
I select on datetimepicker at "04/02/2013"
Output now: 11/02/2013

But I need Output each on weekly
11/02/2013
18/02/2013
25/02/2013 >>> To Current Week
```

I try loop While, But don't work.

Thanks you for your time. :)

Comment: You should use `DateTime`s, not `String`s.  You will then have nice methods like `AddDays()`, which you can call in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a while loop until the datetime is greater than today?

You want to use DateTime rather than Date, so you can compare to a DateTime.Now

You want to set your actual DatePicker value to a variable, else it will always be the same and you will just get an infinite loop.

```
    Dim datePickerValue As DateTime = DateTimePicker.Value
    Dim strDate As Date = DateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Dim strDateWeek As String
    Dim strDateNow As String = DateAdd("d", 0, Now.ToLongDateString())

    While datePickerValue < DateTime.Now()
     strDateWeek = DateAdd("d", +7, datePickerValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
     datePickerValue = DateAdd("d", +7, datePickerValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
     ListBox1.Items.Add(strDateWeek)
   End While
```

Just done it on my VS using your naming conventions and this works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I didn't have used VB, but maybe I can help?
In your code, using while could be a wrong choice perhaps you could use a for with a break instead.

```
for I = 1 to 10
Dim strDateWeek As String = DateAdd("d", +7 * i, dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
.
.
.
```

or

```
while(...)
I += 1
Dim strDateWeek As String = DateAdd("d", +7 * i, dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim dtAux As Date = dateTimePicker.Value
Dim dtEnd As Date = Date.Today.AddDays(7 - dt.DayOfWeek)

While dtAux <= dtEnd
    ListBox1.Items.Add(dtAux.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
    dtAux = dtAux.AddDays(7)
End While
```

The date `dtEnd` is the last day of the current week, if you want the loop to stop on the current date simply change the while condition to:
`While dtAux <= Date.Today`